# Use proxy without entering proxy IP in the browser

Tags: linux, proxy

I have about 100 users, and am using linux proxy server.  I dont want the users to enter the IP address in the browser

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Provide me a solution, not pages to read.

Comment: That attitude won't encourage people to provide answers. In fact there's a definite pattern to your questions and comments. You need to start helping yourself a little, instead of just expecting everything to be handed to you as a finished solution.

Comment: sudo make me a sandwich.

Answer (score 5):

A transparent proxy should do the trick ..., also called an intercepting proxy. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Intercepting_proxy_server

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what OS your clients use (and depending on whether there's more than one OS in use), depending on whether or not you have Active Directory (and depending on whether or not your clients are full AD clients), depending on what browsers you use (and depending on whether there's more than one browser in use), this could be very simple or very messy.  You really need to give more info, but to get you started what you can do is:

- Research where proxy server settings are stored for your client OS and browser(s)
- Research how logon scripts work in your network environment
- Research how to use those logon scripts to change proxy settings

*This is not necessarily the best way to do it*.  We quite simply do *not* know enough about the rest of your network environment at the moment, and a solution that's appropriate to one environment is not always appropriate to other environments.

So please, if you want something other than just links to read, and if you don't want your question to be marked down further, start filling in the gaps in our knowledge and we might be able to supply more specific answers.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the proxy autoconfig system: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config

Answer (score 0):

This can be done yes, via fairly standard routing - that said we'd need a lot more information from you if you wanted us to tell you how - but basically yes.

Comment: what info do you require?

Comment: switch and/or router details, IP ranges, loads really, just get someone who knows your network and routing to have a look.

Comment: i just have a linux box, using cisco switch, ip anything from 192.168.x.x

Comment: that's still nowhere near enough information to give you a solution for this. You need someone to come and sort this for you.